# Is it possible to simplify a formula giving the average number of up-downs in a Motzkin path?

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

I had a question:
To find the statistic's average of the UDs (Up-Down) in Motzkin paths.
I solved it but finally i got something in the statistic that I tried a lot to simplify but did not succeed unfortunately!
I got that the statistic = $$\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} c_i(2i+1) {\binom{(n+1)}{(n-2i)}}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n/2} c_i {n \choose (n-2i)}}$$
$c_i$ is the $i$-th Catalan number. 
How can I simplify that?

How can I get the variance by using this complicated formula?

Comment: UD = Uniform Distribution ? Maybe, take a look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.3093.pdf

Comment: No , it is an up-down step in Motzkin path @JeanMarie

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your too general title (mentionning a combinatorics formula...) in order to attract more people on your question.

Comment: Maybe Motzkin numbers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number can be used in the denominator (consider the even case n=2m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given OPs expression we can find the sequence of numbers of the numerator 
\begin{align*}
&\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{2j+1}{j+1}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{n+1}{n-2j}\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
&\qquad=\left(1,2,6,16,45,126,357,1\ 016,2\,907,8\,350,24\,068,\ldots\right)
\end{align*}
archived as  *[A005717](https://oeis.org/A005717)* in  OEIS  as well as   the sequence of numbers of the denominator
\begin{align*}
&\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{1}{j+1}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{n}{n-2j}\right)_{n\geq 0}\\
&\qquad=\left(1,1,2,4,9,21,51,127,323,835,2\,188,5\,798,\ldots\right)
\end{align*}
archived as  *[A001006](https://oeis.org/A001006)* in OEIS.

Since both entries do not provide a closed formula we rather don't expect a simplification.

Comment: Yes but then how can i find the variance using this statistic? , it would be complicated!@ Markus Scheuer

Comment: @Maths1999_:  I  agree.  This seems to  be somewhat  difficult. Maybe  you want  to ask  for the variance in a question by its own.